# Using a Trusted Root (NOT Self-Signed) Certificate Under IIS Express

Tags: ssl, iis-express

Is it possible to install a Traditional publically trusted certificate using IIS Express?  My googling is producing such noise about how to do it for a self-signed certificate that I can't seem to find any documentation about such a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears no-one has documented how to do this, but I appear to have succeeded with key information from Scott Hanselman's blog on [IIS Express and SSL](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx).

1. Ensure your certificate is in your computer account's "Personal" certificate store. (This will be true if already in use by IIS.)
2. In your VS Web project, use the properties of the project node to enable SSL with IIS Express. Make a note of the port number.
3. Use the tools to get the fingerprint of your "real" certificate (without the spaces).
4. Run (all use of `netsh` needs an elevated command prompt)

   ```
   netsh http dump sslcert
   ```

   and you should see an entry for `IP:Port` with value `0.0.0.0:YourPort`
   where *YourPort* is the port number noted above.
5. Remove this entry:

   ```
   netsh http remove sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:YourPort
   ```
6. And an entry with your certificate

   ```
   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:YourPort appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74a} certhash=YourCertificateFingerprint
   ```

   That GUID seems to be the one associated with all the IIS Express
   entries dumped above.

Comment: Spot on my friend!  Many many many a thank. I was about to use NGINX as a reverse proxy to do it for IIS.